# understanding the decorators and need to return inside wrapper function

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

This is the code from api.py

```
def route(self,path):
       if path in self.routes :
           raise AssertionError('Such route already exists')
       def wrapper(handler):
           self.routes[path] =handler
           print(colorama.Fore.GREEN,"handler check",handler)
           return handler
       return wrapper
```

And this the code from the app.py

```
from api import API
app = API(templates_dir="templates")
from middleware import Middleware

@app.route("/home")
def home (request,response):
    response.text ='Hello from home function'
  
@app.route("/about")    
def about(request,response):
    response.text ='Hello from about function'    
    
@app.route("/hello/{name}")
def greeting(request, response, name):
    response.text = f"Hello, {name}"
```

I am having difficulty in understanding how route decorator works? I see that it takes in a parameter "/about" and "/home" but why do we need to return the reference to the handler in the route decorator.
A clear explanation should really help.

Comment: Whatever the decorator returns is what gets assigned to the name of the function being decorated.  If your decorator didn't return anything, then `home`, `about`, and `greeting` would all end up with a value of None, making it impossible to call the functions directly.

Answer (score 0):

So `route` is in a class that looks something like this:

```
class API:
    routes = {}

    def route(self, path):
        if path in self.routes :
            raise AssertionError('Such route already exists')
        def wrapper(handler):
            self.routes[path] =handler
            print(colorama.Fore.GREEN,"handler check",handler)
            return handler
       return wrapper

   def handle(self, path, request):
       if path in self.routes:
           response = Response()
           self.routes[path](request, response)
           send_to_client(response)
       raise NotFound()
```

When you use

```
@app.route("/home")
def home(request, response):
    response.text ='Hello from home function'
```

this is the same as doing something like:

```
def home_function(request, response):
    response.text ='Hello from home function'

home = app.route("/home")(home_function)
```

First we're calling `app.route` with the argument `"/home"`. First thing this does is check if we already have a route called `/home`. Then it returns the new function, the one that's called `wrapper`.

Now we call `wrapper` with the function we want to handle the `/home` path with. What this does is add to the `dict` a mapping from the path (`/home`) to the function that we want to call to handle this path.

The same thing happens for all decorated functions.

Now when we want to handle an incoming request, you can imaging something a bit like the `handle` function runs. We know that every key of the `routes` mapping is going to be a path, and every value is going to be a function that takes a request and a response. So then we just need to get the right function, and call the it appropriately.

Does that make sense?